# Client/Multithreaded Server needs to respond to all clients in C

Tags: c, multithreading, server, client, broadcasting

I'm a beginner at coding, so I'm having a bit of trouble to finish this code. I'm supposed to make a client/multithreaded server communication, and everything's working fine. The one thing missing is that the server should send the message received from one client to all the other clients, and so far I've only managed to make the server reply to the client that sent the message, and not the others. PS.: Some of the code is in portuguese, but is basically "recieve and send message". Any help is good :)

The server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void enviar_mensagem_cliente(int id_socket, char* mensagem){       
    int tamanho = strlen(mensagem) + 1; 

    printf("Servidor: tamanho da mensagem a enviar ao cliente: %d\n", tamanho);

    write(id_socket, &tamanho, sizeof(tamanho));

    printf("Servidor: enviando mensagem ao cliente: %s\n", mensagem);

    write(id_socket, mensagem, tamanho);
}

int recebe_mensagem_cliente(int id_socket_cliente){      
    while(1){   
        int tamanho;

        if(read(id_socket_cliente, &tamanho, sizeof(tamanho)) == 0)   
            return 0;

        printf("Servidor: tamanho da mensagem a receber do cliente:  %d\n", tamanho);    

        char *mensagem = (char*) malloc(tamanho);

        read(id_socket_cliente, mensagem, tamanho);

        printf("Servidor: recebendo mensagem do cliente: %s\n", mensagem);

        enviar_mensagem_cliente(id_socket_cliente, mensagem);    
        free(mensagem);
    } 
}

void *conversa(void *arg){       
    int cliente_socket_fd = (intptr_t) arg;

    recebe_mensagem_cliente(cliente_socket_fd);

    close(cliente_socket_fd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){        
    const char* const nome_socket = argv[1];        
    int socket_fd;        
    struct sockaddr_un nome; 

    socket_fd = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    nome.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;

    strcpy(nome.sun_path, nome_socket);

    bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &nome, SUN_LEN(&nome));       
    listen(socket_fd, 5);

    pthread_t id_thread;

    do{            
        struct sockaddr_un nome_cliente;             
        socklen_t cliente_nome_len;            
        int cliente_socket_fd; 

        cliente_socket_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &nome_cliente, &cliente_nome_len);

        printf("cliente_socket_fd = %d\n", cliente_socket_fd);

        pthread_create(&id_thread,NULL,conversa,(void *)(intptr_t)cliente_socket_fd);
    } while(1); 

    close(socket_fd);

    unlink(nome_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int recebe_mensagem_servidor(int id_socket_servidor){       
    int tamanho;

    if(read(id_socket_servidor, &tamanho, sizeof(tamanho)) == 0)                
        return 0;

    printf("Cliente: tamanho da mensagem a receber do servidor: %d\n", tamanho);    

    char *mensagem = (char*) malloc(tamanho);

    read(id_socket_servidor, mensagem, tamanho);

    printf("Cliente: recebendo mensagem do servidor: %s\n", mensagem);

    free(mensagem);
}

void enviar_mensagem_servidor(int id_socket, char* mensagem){        
    int tamanho = strlen(mensagem) + 1; 

    printf("Cliente: tamanho da mensagem a enviar: %d\n", tamanho);

    write(id_socket, &tamanho, sizeof(tamanho));

    printf("Cliente: enviando mensagem para o servidor: %s\n", mensagem);

    write(id_socket, mensagem, tamanho);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){        
    const char* const nome_socket = argv[1];       
    int socket_fd; 

    while(1){        
        socket_fd = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);        
        struct sockaddr_un nome;    
        nome.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;

        strcpy(nome.sun_path, nome_socket);

        connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&nome, SUN_LEN(&nome));

        char *mensagem = NULL;   
        size_t tamanho = 0;

        printf("Insira start para começar:");

        getline(&mensagem, &tamanho, stdin);

        mensagem[strlen(mensagem)-1] = '\0';  

        while(strcmp(mensagem,"start") != 0){       
            printf("Insira start para começar:");      
            getline(&mensagem, &tamanho, stdin);    
            mensagem[strlen(mensagem)-1] = '\0';        
         }

        while(strcmp(mensagem,"end") != 0){         
            enviar_mensagem_servidor(socket_fd, mensagem);    
            recebe_mensagem_servidor(socket_fd); 

            printf("Introduza a sua mensagem:");

            getline(&mensagem, &tamanho, stdin);

            mensagem[strlen(mensagem)-1] = '\0';
        }            
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a piece of advice: always check the result of the function you call (read, write, connect...). They could fail (in same cases you'll have to manage a remote peer disconnection) and they could send/receive less data than the amount you asked them for.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Roberto! :)